# If a function is onto, does the function also have an inverse?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Say a function is defined and we find that it is indeed onto (surjective). Does this mean the function also has an inverse function?

Comment: To have an inverse, it must be a bijection (both injective and surjective) since if it fails to be injective then it “loses” information by mapping two points into one, and there is no way of inverting this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f\colon A\to B$ is onto, then there exists a function $g\colon B\to A$ such that $g\circ f=\operatorname{id}_A$ (given $b\in B$, let $g(b)$ be any $a\in A$ with $f(a)=b$, which exists per surjectivity). But this function need not be unique, nor do we have $f\circ g=\operatorname{id}_B$ (i.e., $g$ is only a left inverse), and in fact the existence of $g$ is not "constructive" in that in general it requires the Axiom of Choice.